# How can i style `td` in table row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show text `currently recording` to the right and bottom of the `<td>` , I am trying to set `padding-bottom` just for `<p>` but it moved whole `td` value , Any idea ?

> main.html/main.css

```css
.current-file-text {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>{{file.filename}}<p class="pull-right current-file-text" ng-if="file.mostRecent"><small>currently recording</small></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use <br> after {{file.filename}} and then add style at p "float:right"

Comment: `td{ text-align: right;
    vertical-align: bottom; }`

Comment: @SumanKalyan NOOOO! Do NOT use `<br>` for styling, just to end a line in running text (eg. `<p>I want this line<br>to break</p>`). @OP you might want to try this: `.current-file-text p { padding-top: 2em; text-align: right; }`

Comment: @giorgio this did'nt do anything

Comment: Are you trying to move the `small` element out of the `td`? If so, use absolute positioning. Otherwise, what do you want exactly? Can you provide a mocked -up screenshot of how you want it to look?